# Can't show method definition if Eclipse recognizes a warning on the method

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In Eclipse, when I mouse hover over a built-in method, it displays a method definition including stuff like what the method does, input objects, return objects etc.

If I have a yellow line (warning) under the method I'm trying to use, I can't get the mouse-over to show the definition.

If I try hitting F3, I get a "The Jar of this class file belongs to container "Android 1.6" blah blah blah."

How do I show the definition of the method I am using when there is a warning?

Comment: +1 This annoys the sh*t out of me too! I hope someone has an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those informations are named "javadoc". To show it, juste type `<alt+shift+Q then J>` or go in menu `Window > Show View > Javadoc`

Comment: I tried playing around with this, but it shows me my own method that the built-in method call is inside of.

Comment: put the cursor in the middle of the name of the method which you want the javadoc